# Unable to find how to update the Network speed in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-esxi, cisco-nexus

I want to understand where the value of Network speed is found in Windows and the options to change it.

I am using the Windows Sysinternals bginfo, which generates desktop backgrounds that include important information about the system.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/bginfo

It shows me that the Network Speed is 4GB.

I do not doubt that it is correct. I have see the performance during busy times and it never goes over 3.4GB.

The closest thing I can think of is Link speed

Get-NetAdapter is showing that the NIC speed is set to 10Gbps.

```
C:\Windows\System32>wmic NIC where NetEnabled=true get Name,Speed
Name                      Speed
vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter  10000000000

PS C:\Users\xxxxx> Get-NetAdapter

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             --------- Ethernet0                 vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter                      5 Up           xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx        10 Gbps
```

Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo shows the speed in GT/s, which is Gigatransfers per second.  1 GT/s is 8 times bigger than a GB/s

```
PS C:\Users\xxxxx> get-NetAdapterHArdwareInfo

Name                           Segment Bus Device Function Slot NumaNode PcieLinkSpeed PcieLinkWidth Version
----                           ------- --- ------ -------- ---- -------- ------------- ------------- -------
Ethernet0                            0  11      0        0  192               5.0 GT/s            32 1.0
```

There are no QoS rules set on the Windows machine.

Running Get-NetQosPolicy showed nothing.

It is a virtual machine, Esxi 7.0U3, on a VMware environment.
The underlying vmnics look fine.

`````
   [xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx:~] esxcfg-nics vmnic2 -l
Name    PCI          Driver      Link Speed      Duplex MAC Address       MTU    Description
vmnic0  0000:62:00.0 nenic       Up   20000Mbps  Full   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 1500   Cisco Systems Inc Cisco VIC Ethernet NIC
vmnic1  0000:62:00.1 nenic       Up   20000Mbps  Full   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 9000   Cisco Systems Inc Cisco VIC Ethernet NIC
vmnic2  0000:62:00.2 nenic       Up   20000Mbps  Full   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 9000   Cisco Systems Inc Cisco VIC Ethernet NIC
vmnic3  0000:62:00.3 nenic       Up   20000Mbps  Full   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 9000   Cisco Systems Inc Cisco VIC Ethernet NIC
vmnic4  0000:62:00.4 nenic       Up   20000Mbps  Full   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 9000   Cisco Systems Inc Cisco VIC Ethernet NIC
vmnic5  0000:62:00.5 nenic       Up   20000Mbps  Full   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 1500   Cisco Systems Inc Cisco VIC Ethernet NIC
    ````


There do not appear to be any setting caps:

esxcli system settings advanced -o '/Disk/Throughput'


 Path: /Disk/BandwidthCap
   Type: integer
   Int Value: 4294967294
   Default Int Value: 4294967294
   Min Value: 10
   Max Value: 4294967294
   String Value:
   Default String Value:cap on disk throughput (IO/s) usage
   Valid Characters:
   Description: cap on disk bandwidth (KB/s) usage

   Path: /Disk/ThroughputCap
   Type: integer
   Default Int Value: 4294967294
   Int Value: 4294967294
   Min Value: 10
   Max Value: 4294967294
   String Value:
   Default String Value:
   Valid Characters:
   Description: 

There are no limitations set on the Port groups and no Network I/O Control rules or anything on the VDS.
`````